# PyPDF2 no permissions to save a pdf on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, pypdf

I have a web tool to encrypt pdf files with a password. The problem i have is, that my Flask app or the PyPDF2 module has no permission to save a pdf file into a specific directory. I tried the Flask app with the tool on my local Windows machine and it works fine. When i try to run the tool on my Ubuntu root machine and the code gets to the line where the pdf file gets saved using this command `pdf_file.save(file_path)` the app crashes. The log files tell me this:

```
File "/home/admin/flask/application.py", line 251, in site_pdfencryption
    pdf_file.save(file_path)
  File "/home/admin/flask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3066, in save
    dst = open(dst, "wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/admin/flask/static/pdf/Python_Flask_Code_Prettier.pdf'
```

The directory is existing and the file too. I think there is a permission issue but i have no idea what file has less permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the folder was created by the root user and then tried to access with an other user with less permissions. I just removed the folder and recreated that with the other user